# Reload button on navigation controller on window.xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

heres my issue, I have a tabbar as the root controller, I then have tabs which are navigation controllers. ( all this is done in Interface Builder )

each navigation controller has a view controller. one of these view controllers have a table view.

on the navigation controller of this table view, I want a item button which reloads the table view.

i know to use reloadData.

I have linked the item button up to a IBAction in the view controller of the navigation controller by making a new NSObject in the mainWindow.xib pointing to this view controller. in the view controller I have this IBAction

```
-(IBAction)reloadTable:(id)sender
```

{
    NSLog(@"RELOADDDDING");
    [self.tableViewIB reloadData];
}

The NSlog is displayed, but the table is not reloading.

I have tried with and without the self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same setup with the exact same issue. Below is how I fixed it. Put this code in the view controller with the Table.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


    //reload table now that we have a good array to show
    [self.view reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

**Updated in response to your comment**

Add this code to the action of your button being pushed

```
//button was pushed code
TableViewController * vc = (TableViewController *)[[TableViewController alloc] init];
//this tableview should be named whatever you have your table named as.
[vc.tableView reloadData];
[vc release];
```

Comment: i want it to reload tho when my navigation item button has been pressed? i have it reloading fine when the view is viewed

Comment: any reason why it comes up with this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a2f000'the view isnt a tableviewcontroller, it is a view controller with a tableview.

Comment: same issue as before now, its calling the ibaction but not refreshing the table, i have the outlet set to vc.tableViewIB which is linked to my tableView in IB.

Answer (score 0):

I had asked the exact same question few minutes back - - -  [This might be a simple question. HELP with Resetting UITableViewCells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537634/this-might-be-a-simple-question-help-with-resetting-uitableviewcells)

Just do this !

1. Assign `TableView` as a property.
2. Reload it in `ViewWillAppear`

Comment: i want it to reload tho when my navigation item button has been pressed? i have it reloading fine when the view is viewed