# This might be a simple question. HELP with Resetting UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a serious doubt. It may be simple, but I need some help with this.

I have a view (view1) and I navigate to (view2). There is a tableView in View 2 with some textFields (added as a SubView) , and I add some data to the textFields in the UITableViewCells.

I press the back button, and I go back to view 1.

If I navigate again to view 2, the textFields are in the exact same state as I had left it before. I want it to be nil, and show the placeholders in them. How do I make the textFields nil again without disrupting all the other data ?

I used NSUserDefaults in view 1 to let view 2 know that I am navigating. But ... the method
    `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and `viewDidLoad` does not seem to be called again. Only if it is called again, I can make the textFields inside the uitableViewCells `nil`.

Could someone tell me how I can call the tableViewCells everytime a navigate to view2 ?

Comment: You are obviously not reloading your 2nd view but reusing it (which is good). Hence viewDidLoad wont help but viewWillAppear might do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot believe I missed this. I do not know if I should delete this question...

1. I used a simple `[tableView reloadData]`;
2. Used it in `viewDidAppear`;

These two simple things did the trick !

Answer (score 0):

To get your textFields to return to their original state, you'd be best off using some logic in the `viewDidDisappear` method.  In the most basic form, whenever the view disappears, you'll find the `textField` instances (by either having direct references or by searching the tableView subviews) and sending `textField.text = @"";` to each.  This will clear the text out.  If you need to store any of the text, you can, before clearing it, call something like `NSString *myText = textField.text;` and do what you need with it, as well as do any other checks or storage before you finish with the view

Comment: Any time, sir.  I swear we must end up getting on Stack Overflow at the same time, haha.  Also, very glad to see that you found a simpler solution above.  Less work is always better

Comment: i do indeed.  i'll see if i can get a link to it........[here's my public profile](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/justin-crawford/35/770/546)

Comment: Yo ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539784/guys-i-need-help-with-self-view-reloadinputviews

Comment: haha, will do.  looks like i was way late getting around to it anyway

Comment: sorry, i wasn't around for the past 4 days or so (had a mini-vacation).  what do you need help with?  i'll be more than happy to try